# Unable to access a repository with Eclipse SVN plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, user-agent, firewall

I have a problem to access the following SVN repository http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/ using Eclipse and Subclipse or Subversive plugins and JavaHL or SVNKit.
I have this problem only with Eclipse on the computer in my office. With Firefox it works fine and at home it works fine, even with Eclipse.

The error is

```
Get revision properties operation failed.
RA layer request failed
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (400 ) in response to PROPFIND request for '/svn'
```

It's likely a firewall issue and a question of user-agent.

I've already asked to the network administrator to check the firewall configuration and he will probably manage to solve it but I'd like to know if there are any other solutions ? For instance, "hacking" the default Eclipse SVN client user-agent, or anything else?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP uses port 80, and I doubt your office is blocking port 80. Does this URL work in a web browser from your office? If it does, see if there's a proxy setting for http.

You might be able to set it up in the `$HOME/.subversion/server` file. Look under the `[global]` section and look for the proxy configurations listed there.

Comment: No proxy and as I said, it's likely a question of user-agent.